# Translating max function in MatLab to numpy

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, max

I want to translate the following MatLab code into Numpy.

```
% MatLab
[selVals, colAssignment] = max(A, [], 2);
```

According to the NumPy for Matlab users guide on the Numpy site, the syntax for converting max(..., [], 2) is

```
# Numpy
selVals = A.max(1)
```

However, this just gives the numpy equivalent of selVals. It doesn't give the colAssignment. How would I get the colAssignment in Numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `A` is a `numpy` array, you could this in a single line of code.

```py
selVals, colAssignment = A.max(axis=1), A.argmax(axis=1)
```

Alternatively:

```py
colAssignment = A.argmax(axis=1) #index
selVals = A[:, colAssignment] #value
```

Comment: FYI: `selVals = A[:, colAssignment]` does not give the same result as the Matlab code.  It creates a 2-d array containing the full column that contains each row maximum.  See my answer for how to get just the maximum values.

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser. I upvoted your answer too. I marked the first as the answer.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I voted for the answer that appeared top of the list. Isn't that the chronologically first answer? If I did incorrectly, my apologies.

Comment: No, it isn't chronological.  I think it is random.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in a single function call.  To get `colAssignment`, call `argmax`:

```
setVals = A.max(axis=1)
colAssignment = A.argmax(axis=1)
```

Depending on the size of `A`, it might be more efficient to get `colAssignment` first, and use it to pull out the maximum values from `A`:

```
colAssignment = A.argmax(axis=1)
setVals = A[np.arange(len(A)), colAssignment]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a multidimensional list , you can do is like this:

```
a = [[0, 1, 2],
     [3, 4, 5],
     [0,7,8],
     [9,10,11],
     [0, 1, 2],
     [1, 4, 5],
     [0,17,8],
     [9,5,1],
     [15,7,8]]

selVals, colAssignment = np.array(a).max(0), np.array(a).argmax(0)

# output 
# selVals = array([15, 17, 11]), colAssignment= array([8, 6, 3]))
# The first array contains maximum numbers in each column and the second array its indexes
```